# How can I make Eclipse output std:out to a standard windows console

Tags: windows, eclipse, console

As eclipse users know, eclipse captures the output of std out and err by default and dumps it into the console that is integrated with the IDE.

I would like eclipse to just use a standard windows cmd instance to display std:out and std:err by default, the way most other IDE's do.  Does anybody know how to set this up?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if it's possible to redirect to a proper console window, however it *can* redirect to a file (which is more useful IMHO) - under Run/Debug settings -> Common -> Standard Input and Output (it can even write to console and file at the same time).

Comment: Once you have output being written to a file, you could use tail to read the file. There are GUI and command line tail utilities for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could probably extend/replace the existing Console view and add an option to write to stdout/stderr.

If you're talking about a Java-program and you want it to **open** a new console window for stdout/stderr, you will probably have to modify the JDT launcher.

Why would you want to do that? I find it much more convenient to have stdout/stderr in the Eclipse console.

Answer (score -1):

Since you haven't said why you prefer stdout in a windows cmd window i'll make some assumptions:
- you only want to move the window around outside of Eclipse

In the case above you can drag the console window by the tab outside of Eclispe and you open another window you can move around like a cmd prompt.

Answer (score -1):

When you run a java .class from the cmd it automatically outputs to the windows CMD. Either grab the most recent .class file from your bin folder or compile it yourself using javac. then just go to the windows cmd where the class file is and run it using        java yourClassesName.class      and it will automatically write all output to the windows cmd.