# An Eclipse console view that respects ANSI color codes?

Tags: eclipse, console, ansi-escape

The output from ScalaTest is colored to distinguish different states, but these end up as control codes and

```
[34m Annoying garbage
```

Is there any way to convince the Eclipse console to either respect or ignore these sequences, or to plug in a view that will?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I am successfully using this plugin for Eclipse - [ANSIConsole](http://mihai-nita.net/2013/06/03/eclipse-plugin-ansi-in-console/)

[image]

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor Does the fact that you didn't switch the checkmark correctly suggest it did _not_ work?

Comment: No sorry, not using Eclipse ATM

Comment: Excellent. Works like a charm and it's using the regular Eclipse console. Much easier than the accepted answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work out of the box with ncurses; the console understands some escape codes (such as changing the text colour) but others (including whatever it is ncurses prints with `initscr()` and `endwin()` get printed verbatim.  I take it I need to set the `TERM` environment variable in the Run Configurations to something Ansi Console understands, but `xterm`, `ansi`, and a few others I've tried don't work.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work with ncurses is mentioned on the website: "Since this plugin hooks into LineStyleListener, it cannot do anything other than changing the style of the current output. So no cursor movements, clear screen, etc."

Comment: It has annoying problems with multiline log entries (which have color code only on the first line): https://github.com/mihnita/ansi-econsole/issues/3

Comment: this addon is a little bit slow- does any one have a faster alternative?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the jansi library.
Add System.setProperty("jansi.passthrough", "true"); to make it work and override jansi's passthrough detection.

Comment: This does not seem to work in Eclipse 2020-12. Is there anything I have to do to enable ANSI support once installed?

Answer (score 29):

The *Target Management Terminal* plugin for Eclipse understands ANSI escape characters, including color codes. I use it to run `sbt` with `ScalaTest`.

The original *Target Management Terminal* plugin was designed to access remote systems. However, if you are running on Linux, Mac, or Solaris but **not Windows**, you can use the *Local Terminal* plugin which adds the ability to attach directly to a local shell or program.

Installing the *Local Terminal* plugin automatically installs the *Target Management Terminal*, so you just need to install the local terminal:

#### Installing the *Local Terminal* plugin

1. Select *Help -> Install New Software...* from the Eclipse menu
2. Select the primary update site for you release of Eclipse (e.g., Ganymede, Helios, Indigo)
3. Select *General Tools -> Local Terminal*
4. Follow normal procedure to install the plugin (click next, accept license, restart eclipse, etc).

If you are running on a platform not supported by the *Local Terminal* plugin, you can still use *Target Management Terminal* with SSH or Telnet:

#### Installing the *Target Management Terminal* plugin

1. Select *Help -> Install New Software...* from the Eclipse menu
2. Select the primary update site for you release of Eclipse (e.g., Ganymede, Helios, Indigo)
3. Select *Mobile and Device Development -> Target Management Console*
4. Follow normal procedure to install the plugin (click next, accept license, restart eclipse, etc).

#### Using

1. Select *Window -> Show View -> Other* from the Eclipse menu
2. Select the *Terminal -> Terminal* view.
3. Click the green Connect button in the view, and enter details to connect to your local system. If you installed the Local Terminal plugin, one of the options is "Local Program". By default, there is program defined for your local shell, but you can setup others. For example, I have an entry for sbt.

If you are more used to white-on-black, you might want to:

1. Open Eclipse preferences
2. Select *Terminal*
3. Check *Invert terminal colors*

Comment: Wow, I'd given up on this one. Thanks for dropping by!

Comment: How can I direct the stdout calls `System.out.println()` to this Terminal, and not to the default Eclipse Console ?

Comment: @Mark: you might have better luck getting an answer if you ask in a new question (instead of asking in a comment).

Comment: @Mark, check the answer of ianinini. That works in default console. If not specified, the console font and color remains default; if escaped with ANSI, will colorize.

Comment: It looks like the local terminal is no longer available - I was unable to find it for eclipse 2022-03.

Answer (score 15):

This works brilliantly for me:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console

Simply install it and it automatically modifies the behaviour of Eclipse's default console. (You can easily disable it with a button provided.)

I have used this for running code that outputs escape codes to modify the text colour. It behaves exactly as expected.

Comment: The previous answers are a bit old, but this plugin is a newer and works good.

Comment: I can't get it to work on Eclipse 2020-12. What is that button and where is it?

Answer (score 6):

No need for an Eclipse plugin with Eclipse 4.25 (part of the Eclipse 2022-09 simultaneous release):

> ### [Support for ANSI escape codes in Console](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.25/platform.php#debug-ansi-support)
>
> Console interprets ANSI escape codes to produce styled output.
>
> Supports 16 colors / 256 colors / true-colors for foreground and background, color palettes, and attributes like bold, italic, underline, invert, conceal, strike, crossed-out, framed:
>
> [image: Screenshot of a console with colored text -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.25/images/ansi_sample.png]
>
> Only "`CSI n m`" (**SGR**, **Select Graphic Rendition**) control sequences are supported.
> They set display attributes, but cannot be used to change the content of the output (erase actions, cursor positioning, scrolling).
> Non-SGR sequences are not interpreted, but are recognized and hidden, so you will not see them.
>
> This functionality is available for all the text output to the standard output or standard error.
> It works for Java, C/C++, Perl, Python, shell, Groovy, Maven, any Eclipse supported language.
>
> Preferences:
>
> [image: Screenshot of the ANSI support preferences dialog -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.25/images/ansi_prefs.png]

Answer (score 4):

You can use this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/elt/

See http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=2428

Comment: This plugin allows the user to display a colour-capable terminal with a shell prompt.  However, it doesn't seem to allow the user to direct their program output to this terminal.

Answer (score 1):

How about redirecting your output to a file and then just "tail -f" it? Similar to this question: [How can I make Eclipse output std:out to a standard windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263952/how-can-i-make-eclipse-output-stdout-to-a-standard-windows-console)

Update: there are also some options listed at [Colorize logs in eclipse console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233790/colorize-logs-in-eclipse-console). Even if that doesn't work, it might be a starting point on how to swap out the standard console plugin.

Comment: If I can I'd like to keep the output in Eclipse.

Comment: Downvote on this. The question was "An eclipse console view that respects ANSI color codes". Not how to pipe eclipse output into a terminal.