# Strange characters in Nodeclipse console

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I am seeing strange characters in the console output when using Nodeclipse.  Any idea what might be causing this?  I don't think it is an Eclipse encoding issue since most of the text is fine.

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debuglog/0.0.2
jade@1.1.4 node_modules\jade
â”œâ”€â”€ commander@2.1.0
â”œâ”€â”€ character-parser@1.2.0
```

[image]

Comment: Actually here there are 2 issues: using UTF-8 for workspace (for npm) and ANSI escape sequences (for express)

Answer (score 2):

As noted in other answers, these are ANSI escape sequences.  The [ansi-econsole](https://github.com/mihnita/ansi-econsole) eclipse plugin displays these correctly, as noted in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10560829/277307).

[image: NPM output with ansi-econsole eclipse plugin]

[image: Express output with ansi-econsole eclipse plugin]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's printing an [escape sequence for colored text](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html), but Eclipse isn't handling it right. Most programs have an option to disable colored output for situations like this.

Comment: Eclipse is not all software that runs on top of it.

Comment: Now it can with Ansi Console plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It is a VT escape sequence all right.

But npm is showing colors only when the output stream is not a TTY. So it looks like a bug in eclipse/nodeclipse because stderr looks like a TTY when in fact it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Change workspace character encoding to UTF-8

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding
```

You should have read build-int Help, available with <kbd>F1</kbd>

or read it online https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.help/contents/configuration.md#configuration

Comment: -1 This is not related to text file encoding, and pointing out help with `F1` is not very helpful.  The link to nodeclipse's recommended configuration was interesting but not helpful in this instance because it didn't mention how to work with these ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: That was Nodeclipse recommendation and yes there were no ANSI support in Eclipse, now ANSI Console plugin should be recommended http://www.nodeclipse.org/.