# How to use Terminal View in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, console, ansi-escape

By default projects run in Eclipse that has console output will bring focus to the console window and display the output there.

Eclipse has a `Local Terminal` option.  Is there a configuration that will activate this as the output destination for a running project?

Before upgrading to Neon I was using an ansi plugin for the console, which isn't installing properly in this current version ([ansi-escape-console](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console)).  While it might be a temporary glitch, now is a good time to learn how to use the `Local Terminal` alternative.

I'm trying to have the ansi escape codes displayed in scripts like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'

printf "Hello... ${RED}This is red highlighted text ${NC}.\n"
```

**Update:**  I was able to get the `ANSI Escape in Console` plugin from the Marketplace installed.  I still would like to know how to specify the output to the `Local Terminal` view as an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An Eclipse console view that respects ANSI color codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286701/an-eclipse-console-view-that-respects-ansi-color-codes)

Comment: This is different from your link.  When I first asked the question, I thought there was a way to use the terminal view as the default console.  I was asking the community how to activate this method.  I soon learned there isn't such a method.  The two views are different for different purposes.  Reading your link would not have addressed my question.  I eventually discovered they were different features, and Terminal view couldn't be the default output console.  At the same time of answering my question, I provided a resolution for the ANSI decoded in the console view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between the **Console** view and the **Terminal** view.

**Console View**

The console view is a facility for the output of the applications running in IDE of eclipse (for test and debugging).

**Terminal View**

The Terminal View is a terminal emulator for access to the local computer's shell.

While I wanted to see the **Ansi Color** output and other **escaped sequences** of the IDE console running programs, this is done using the Marketplace upgrade of the **ANSI Escape on Console** plugin.

Comment: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console