# Eclipse console not printing colors

Tags: java, eclipse, console, println

I'm trying to print colored text to eclipse console using ANSI Sequences (as described for example here: [How to print color in console using System.out.println?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)).

I've tried multiple approaches, most recently a very implicit one:

```
public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";

System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "*" + ANSI_RESET);
```

but all I'm getting from console is:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are using Windows, it could not work in this way.

Comment: i'm not sure but i think this trick work with netbeans not with eclipse

Comment: The standard Eclipse console does not support ANSI colors. There are some plugins that add this, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6286701/2670892) question

Comment: Install the "ANSI Escape in Console" plugin  
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console  
(from Eclipse Marketplace search for ANSI)