# Print bold text to console output

Tags: java, ansi-escape

I am using eclipse IDE latest version with this plugin:

https://github.com/mihnita/ansi-econsole

or

https://mihai-nita.net/java/

and

https://mihai-nita.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/AECSample.jpg

And like you can see in the picture the plugin should support **italic/bold/underline**

But I can not make it work.
I can not understand why bold, italic and underline does not work I am able to print colored text with ANSI plugin.

I checked here:
[How to print color in console using System.out.println?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)

```
    System.out.println("Hello \u001b[1;31mred\u001b[0m world!");
    System.out.println("\033[0;1m" + "Bold text");
    System.out.println("\u001B[1m" + "I am bold");
```

I want to see italic/underline and bold on console output texts but right now only colors and background colors worth with the plugin

Comment: Not all Consoles can work with these codes or give unexpected results and therefore it's basically a waste of time (in my opinion). If you want to add a little pizazz to your console application then perhaps consider displaying a JOptionPane. You can use HTML to format your text whichever way you like.

Comment: @DevilsHnd But the plugin says it is for eclipse users and if you look at the image you can clearly see bold/italic and underline examples on eclipse console

Comment: Oh..I'm sorry. I was under the assumption that you wanted to utilize these codes for an application you are developing for anyone to use rather than everyone needing Eclipse for which to properly use the app. I assume you've read this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286701/an-eclipse-console-view-that-respects-ansi-color-codes). This sort of thing will always give issues (imho).

Comment: But you can see in the SO Thread link you gave people able to make it work.
My problem is that color is working with this plugin on my eclipse console but bold/underline and italic does not and I do not know why or what am I doing wrong

Comment: I supported, see first screenshot at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console#group-screenshots. But often the bold font is not very "bold" (and if the plugin is configured "Windows style", with bold => intense, that makes it even less visible. Please file a bug if indeed is not bold.