# Special characters not working on my console (sys out) using eclipse

Tags: java

I was trying to clear the console on java using the eclipse IDE and for some reason, the code isn't working how it is supposed to be working. I think it is something to do with me using eclipse and I am wondering if there is an alternative way to do the following code on eclipse.

```
System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
System.out.flush();
```

the result I am getting from this code is...

```
[H[2J
```

if anyone knows away to get around this I will be happy to know.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `flush`. The console you're printing to doesn't seem to support ANSII escape codes (that complicated string you're trying to print out to do stuff). You'll need to use a different method or a different console.

Comment: Create a UTF-16 or other charset file and print there. Like above probably console does not support this charset

Comment: That code prints nothing on my IntelliJ IDEA console.

Comment: Yes Sweeper, that is what I am trying to make it do on my console. On IntelliJ if you were to print something before that then maybe do a Thread.sleep() it would print the original thing but then erase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and they need support from the terminal. The standard terminal doesn't support them, but there are apparently [plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286701/an-eclipse-console-view-that-respects-ansi-color-codes) if you need that support (in Eclipse).

The `flush()` isn't related (or needed) in any way.