# Printing System.out.println() with different colors in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to print any `System.out.println("Hello world");` with some specific color in eclipse.

I have tried `System.err.println()` but it is not synchronized and using the ANSI codes does not work. I guess this problem is specifically for the eclipse, any suggestions?

```
public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
public static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";

System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "This text is red!" + ANSI_RESET);
```

Comment: I don't think so, and it isn't clear why you want to do this; users aren't going to run your program in eclipse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print color in console using System.out.println?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have to output the data in eclipse console for presentation so its specifically for eclipse.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare no that's the same thing as using **ANSI code**  which is not working for eclipse.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10560829/2970947).

Comment: @kunjdesai Have you tried all voted answers?

Comment: @Elliot Frisch This is helpful, thanks!

Comment: @KaustubhKhare Yes, mostly everything!

Comment: After installing the plugin linked to in that answer, your code prints red text in my eclipse console. Best of luck!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, that plugin works fine. Thank you for your help!