# Why my eclipse console output is in encoded format

Tags: eclipse

Guys why is my eclipse console output like this? Please help

[image]

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286701/an-eclipse-console-view-that-respects-ansi-color-codes

Comment: @fukanchik That's an outdated answer. The ANSIConsole is built-in for quite some versions.

Comment: That might be caused by the theme plugin you have installed which tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing load-time weaving which can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. Can you reproduce this issue with the current Eclipse without additional plugins and a fresh workspace?

Comment: The program you are running is trying to use "ANSI control codes" to do fancy things on the console. Eclipse supports setting colours like this (if enabled) but not anything more complex.